# How to simplify this complex DC circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, short-circuit, circuits, circuit-theory

I find it very hard to simplify this circuit. Currently practicing for my removal exam and this was one of the problems I failed on one of my previous exams.

[image]

Especially the middle part makes me so confused and the 0 A section.

UPDATE:

I applied the feedbacks I've gotten so far...

[image]

Did I head in the right direction?

UPDATE NO. 2:

Saw someone do it like this, I don't understand what he did there with the 0A section.

[image]

UPDATE NTH: I understand now. HE DID A WYE-DELTA trasformation! anyways i get it now. thank you!

Comment: A continuous section of a wire can be considered a "node", if that helps the thinking. What is a 0A current source? A point where no current can flow to on or the other direction... Or other way of thinking, what happens if you analyze the circuit source by source.

Comment: Oh so like superposition! Yeah but its that line/wire that jumps over those group of resistors that bothers me the most.

Comment: How do you get from 30 A to 30 V?

Comment: source transformation ma'am/sir? since the current source was parallel with the 1 ohm?

Comment: 4 ohm and 10 ohm are not in series. So, keep them as it is.

Comment: @prashanth yeah i noticed that after too soon enough sir/ma'am. thank you

Answer (score 3):

Some of the simplifications that u could make:

1. 0A current can be considered as open circuit. Then both the 10ohm resistors are in series and the resultant is in parallel with 20ohm.
2. Two nodes of each of the resistors 20, 30, 5, 20 ohm are connected to same nodes. So, they are connected in parallel. The resultant is in series with 1ohm.

Comment: oh those were parallel? i got so confused with the wire in between 20,30 and 5,20. i thought it was a short. (thank you!)